# Inject Angular service in constructor of app.module in Hybrid Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-bootstrap, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I am looking at an Angular hybrid app and its new for me.

Its app.module.ts has providers with upgraded AngularJS services under providers[..]:

It has UpgradeModule injected as:

```
constructor(
    private upgrade: UpgradeModule
) { }
```

Then, there is the following:

```
ngDoBootstrap() {
    const strictDi = typeof this.strictDi === 'boolean' ? this.strictDi : true;
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app'], { strictDi });
}
```

I have an Angular service - AuthTokenService.ts

```
@Injectable
export class AuthTokenService ... {
..
}
```

I have a need where I want to inject this service AuthTokenService in app.module.ts constructor (to do some processing/check at that level before loading app)
However, it looks like in hybrid Angular, I cannot simply inject it as:

```
constructor(
  private upgrade: UpgradeModule,
  private authTokenService: AuthTokenService   // this is how I am trying to inject
) { }
```

When I load the app, it gives an error - `Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.`

Any idea if and how I can inject an Angular service in the constructor of app.module.ts in a hybrid Angular app?

Comment: try this ```@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})```

Comment: @Kardon63 I had tried that but it didn't work

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095911/angular-2-call-service-before-bootstrap

Comment: I do have the AuthTokenService in my provider list in app.module.ts, but it doesn't resolve the error